# How do I make the type of a dictionary inferred from its value in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

Consider this simple config:

```
config = {
    'sentry': {
        'endpoint': '...',
        'server_name': '...',
    },
}
```

let's imagine that it's in fact big (tens of keys on different levels). I'm looking for a way to "infer" the type of config to achieve 3 goals:

1. Suggestions should work fine in VS Code (assume that the keys of `config` are not changed). As currently written, if I type `config[`, IntelliSense  suggests `'sentry'` as expected, but if type `config['sentry'][`, instead of `endpoint, server_name`, it suggests a whole lot of irrelevant stuff (`type, config, add, assert, ......`).

   1. In fact, I'd also like to highlight adding a key (`config['kek'] = 'lol'`) as an error (or allow adding only specific keys)
2. Pylance should highlight reading `config['kek']` as an error (`'kek'` doesn't exist in `config`).
3. The solution should be DRY: I don't want to repeat each key outside the dictionary, I want them to be inferred from its shape.

In TypeScript, I just write

```
const config = {
    sentry: {
        endpoint: '...',
        cserver_name: 'kek',
    },
}
```

and all these goals are achieved automatically, can I get these at least by using some annotation in Python?

Comment: No, you can't have all three. You can define a `typing.TypedDict` that will do exactly this, but it requires repeating the keys one more time in the definition (but is however a perfect match for other points you raised). There's nothing like `as const` assertions in Python your system, if you need complex configuration - probably dict is a bad tool. You can use classes, namedtuples, dataclasses, Pydantic models (with validation and ability to write config in external files) and many other tools, most of which will give you desired autocomplete if typed correctly.

Comment: @STerliakov sounds like a definitive answer, thanks and feel free to post as an answer (with an example showing the usage of `typing.TypedDict`). It least this type of solution looks fine for API payloads and stuff like that. It's pity that the type can't be inferred from the value though